# Credentials don't work when adding Cortana channel to BOT

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, cortana-intelligence

I have been using Teams channel to interact with my BOT but I would like to also add Cortana. When I add the channel I get this message:

```
You can access the Cortana Skills dashboard by signing in with your Microsoft Account (MSA). If you do not have an MSA, you can sign up for one here.
```

We have an MSDN license and our accounts are set up by IT using our corporate email, that's how I'm logged in and I have no problem seeing all the apps, resource groups, etc under the Azure portal. I was also added to a corporate Azure subscription, associated with the same email address. I thought this was enough to access Cortana Dashboard but looks like I need some other type of credentials?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to test your Cortana Skill, you need to be logged into an MSA account on Cortana which is the same account you registered the skill with on dev.botframework.com.  A work account will not work, it *needs* to be an MSA account like @outlook.com.

You can find instructions on how to change your Cortana account [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fbe3b5b-8edf-4373-89d4-b79ba9877895/change-cortana-microsoft-account?forum=win10itprogeneral)

for your follow-up question, You can go back and register your bot like you did the first time.  You will just need to change the APP ID and Password. You do not need to change anything on your LUIS account link the LUIS application in your Luis Dialog like this:

```
[LuisModel("YourModelId", "YourSubscriptionKey")]
    [Serializable]
    public class RootLuisDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
   //your code
}
```

Comment: I registered the bot with my work email account, as well as the LUIS account. Do I now need to create an outlook.com account to register Cortana, and if so, how do I tie the BOT/LUIS to that?

Comment: Are you using Node or C#?

Comment: I am using C# @JasonSowers

Comment: Updated my answer, please let me know if you need clarification

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately is my work account where we have the corporate subscription and payment plan setup, if I register my BOT with a new outlook account I will loose that. Will Cortana be available for AD domain accounts in the future?

Comment: I know it is being explored, but I have no timeline to share with you at this time.